# Could not convert string to float error after one hot encoding

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to make a prediction algorithm that predicts the values of unknown categorical variables. However, I am getting a "cannot convert string to float error" after doing one hot encoding. Here is my code

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

 raw_data =             pd.read_csv('/Users/name/Desktop/CompSci_Projects/Stroke_Prediction_Model/dataset/healthcare-dataset-stroke-data.csv')
 data = raw_data.copy(deep=True)
 data.interpolate(method='linear', inplace = True)
 data
 
 #OneHot encoding
 stuff = data.iloc[:, [1, 5, 6, 7]]
 enc_col = stuff.iloc[:, [0, 1, 2, 3]].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
 data_enc = pd.concat([stuff.iloc[:, [0, 1, 2, 3]], enc_col], axis=1)
 data = pd.concat([data, data_enc], axis=1)
 
 #RandomForest Prediction
 x_columns_to_drop = ['id', 'smoking_status']
 y_columns_to_drop = ['id', 'gender', 'age', 'hypertension', 'heart_disease',      'ever_married', 'work_type', 'Residence_type', 'avg_glucose_level', 'bmi', 'stroke']

 x = data.drop(x_columns_to_drop, axis=1)
 y = data.drop(y_columns_to_drop, axis=1)

 smokestatus_unknown = data[data['smoking_status'] == 'Unknown']
 smokestatus_known =  data[data['smoking_status'] != 'Unknown']

 x_train = smokestatus_known.drop(x_columns_to_drop, axis=1)
 y_train = smokestatus_known.drop(y_columns_to_drop, axis=1)

 pre_test = data[data['smoking_status'] == 'Unknown']
 x_test = pre_test.drop(x_columns_to_drop, axis=1)

 X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

 X_train = x_train
 X_test = x_test
 Y_train = y_train

 classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
 classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Here is my error message

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/2j/350ck5_15yg7p6_0p1lw6t500000gn/T/ipykernel_34414/1322606929.py in ?()
     19 X_test = x_test
     20 Y_train = y_train
     21 
     22 classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
---> 23 classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
     24 
     25 predicted_values = classifier.predict(X_test)
     26 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1147                 skip_parameter_validation=(
   1148                     prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1149                 )
   1150             ):
-> 1151                 return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in ?(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    344         """
    345         # Validate or convert input data
    346         if issparse(y):
    347             raise ValueError("sparse multilabel-indicator for y is not supported.")
--> 348         X, y = self._validate_data(
    349             X, y, multi_output=True, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE
    350         )
    351         if sample_weight is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, cast_to_ndarray, **check_params)
    617                 if "estimator" not in check_y_params:
    618                     check_y_params = {**default_check_params, **check_y_params}
    619                 y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    620             else:
--> 621                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    622             out = X, y
    623 
    624         if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in ?(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1143         raise ValueError(
   1144             f"{estimator_name} requires y to be passed, but the target y is None"
   1145         )
   1146 
-> 1147     X = check_array(
   1148         X,
   1149         accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   1150         accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in ?(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    914                         )
    915                     array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    916                 else:
    917                     array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
--> 918             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    919                 raise ValueError(
    920                     "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
    921                 ) from complex_warning

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py in ?(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    376         # Use NumPy API to support order
    377         if copy is True:
    378             array = numpy.array(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    379         else:
--> 380             array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    381 
    382         # At this point array is a NumPy ndarray. We convert it to an array
    383         # container that is consistent with the input's namespace.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in ?(self, dtype)
   1996     def __array__(self, dtype: npt.DTypeLike | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
   1997         values = self._values
-> 1998         arr = np.asarray(values, dtype=dtype)
   1999         if (
   2000             astype_is_view(values.dtype, arr.dtype)
   2001             and using_copy_on_write()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'
```

I was expecting the could not convert string to float error to go away after one hot encoding, but that was not the case.

Comment: It is hard to help without looking at the data, but from the error it seems that you have a `gender` column you need to map from Male/Female to 1/0.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the new numerical columns to your Dataframe without removing the text ones. This is why you get this error. You can try this instead:

```
#OneHot encoding
stuff = data.iloc[:, [1, 5, 6, 7]]
enc_col = stuff.iloc[:, [0, 1, 2, 3]].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
data = pd.concat([data.drop(data.columns[[1, 5, 6, 7]], axis=1), enc_col], axis=1)
```

I just want to point out this is not one hot encoding, you are doing ordinal encoding.
For this type of encoding you should use [OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder) instead ([LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) is meant for the target, not the input features).
If you want to do one hot encoding, you can use [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder).